# Storing multiple user Inputs from Text Boxes and adding multiple values from Text Boxes?

Tags: vb.net

Here I have a basic Bank Account that allows users to enter their debit and credit amounts along with a memo for each amount. The user can display all transactions and their balance as well. I'm having trouble displaying all the transactions as well as creating an equation to subtract debits from credits. Here is what I have so far, as I have been stuck on this for hours.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim valueDebit As Decimal
    Dim valueCredit As Decimal
    Dim total As Decimal



    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Text = "Mike Smith's Bank Account"
        Lb1.Visible = False
        Lb2.Visible = False
        Lb3.Visible = False
        Tb1.Visible = False
        Tb2.Visible = False
        Bt1.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Cb1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If Tb1.Text = "" Then
            Tb1.Text = "0.00"

        ElseIf Cb1.Text = "Credit" Then
            Lb1.Visible = True
            Lb2.Visible = True
            Lb3.Visible = False
            Tb1.Visible = True
            Tb2.Visible = True
            Lb1.Text = "Enter Credit Amount"
            Lb2.Text = "Describe the Income"
            Bt1.Visible = True

            valueCredit = Convert.ToDecimal(Tb1.Text)



        ElseIf Cb1.Text = "Debit" Then
            Lb1.Visible = True
            Lb2.Visible = True
            Lb3.Visible = False
            Tb1.Visible = True
            Tb2.Visible = True
            Lb1.Text = "Enter Debit Amount"
            Lb2.Text = "Describe the Expense"
            Bt1.Visible = True

            valueDebit = Convert.ToDecimal(Tb1.Text)


        ElseIf Cb1.Text = "Display Transactions" Then
            Lb1.Visible = False
            Lb2.Visible = False
            Lb3.Visible = True
            Tb1.Visible = False
            Tb2.Visible = False
            Bt1.Visible = False


        ElseIf Cb1.Text = "Display Balance" Then
            Lb1.Visible = False
            Lb2.Visible = False
            Lb3.Visible = True
            Tb1.Visible = False
            Tb2.Visible = False
            Lb3.Text = "$"

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Bt1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Bt1.Click
        Cb1.Text = ""
        Tb1.Visible = False
        Tb2.Visible = False
        Lb1.Visible = False
        Lb2.Visible = False
        Tb1.Text = ""
        Tb2.Text = ""

    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Debits are income and Credits are expenses on a bank account.
Secondly, I think a submit-type Button would be ideal in this situation

One option that I tried: make Public Class Transaction, then use a List(of Transaction) and transaction listbox on form. Also using a button for "submitting" the transaction. Then you can use a loop to get the list of transactions and get the total Amount/Balance.

```
Public Class Form1
   'Mod-level variable
   Dim TransactionsList As New List(Of Transaction)      

  'Not exactly sure what all the labels are and the exact layout of your form, 
  'so you can apply this to your code
  Private Sub Cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Cb1.SelectedIndexChanged
     If Tb1.Text = "" Then
        Tb1.Text = "0.00"

     ElseIf Cb1.Text = "Credit" Then
        Lb1.Visible = True
        Lb2.Visible = True
        Lb3.Visible = False
        Tb1.Visible = True
        Tb2.Visible = True
        Lb1.Text = "Enter Credit Amount"
        Lb2.Text = "Describe the Income"
        Bt1.Visible = True

        'valueCredit = Convert.ToDecimal(Tb1.Text) (Handled in buttonClick event)

     ElseIf Cb1.Text = "Debit" Then
        Lb1.Visible = True
        Lb2.Visible = True
        Lb3.Visible = False
        Tb1.Visible = True
        Tb2.Visible = True
        Lb1.Text = "Enter Debit Amount"
        Lb2.Text = "Describe the Expense"
        Bt1.Visible = True

        'valueDebit = Convert.ToDecimal(Tb1.Text) (Handled in buttonClick event)

     ElseIf Cb1.Text = "Display Transactions" Then
        Lb1.Visible = False
        Lb2.Visible = False
        Lb3.Visible = True
        Tb1.Visible = False
        Tb2.Visible = False
        Bt1.Visible = False

        'This is where you loop through list to get your transactions 
        For Each transaction In TransactionList
           'Add each Transaction to the ListBox. Display the data however you like...
            TransactionsListBox.Items.Add(
                  String.Format("{0}: {1:C}. {2}", 
                                transaction.Type, 
                                transaction.Amount, 
                                transaction.Description))
        Next    

    ElseIf Cb1.Text = "Display Balance" Then
        Lb1.Visible = False
        Lb2.Visible = False
        Lb3.Visible = True
        Tb1.Visible = False
        Tb2.Visible = False
        Lb3.Text = "$" 

     End If
  End Sub      

  'Click button to submit the transaction.. 
  'Also easier for data validation, error catching, etc.
   Private Sub SubmitTransactionButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitTransactionButton.Click
      Dim transactionTypeString As String = Cb1.Text
      Dim transactionDescriptionstring As String = Tb2.Text
      Dim transactionAmountDecimal As Decimal 

      'If user enters non-numeric value, exception gets thrown
      Try
          'Convert amount to Decimal
          transactionAmountDecimal = Decimal.Parse(Tb1.Text)          

          'Add to the list of Transactions
          TransactionList.Add(New Transaction( 
                            transactionTypeString, 
                            transactionAmountDecimal,   
                            transactionDescriptionstring))

      Catch FormatExceptionParameter as FormatException
          transactionAmountDecimal = 0D

      End Try


   End Sub   

 End Class


 Public Class Transaction
    Public Sub New(type As String, amount As Decimal, description As String)
        Me.Type = type
        Me.Amount = amount
        Me.Description = description    

        'Optional depending on how you want to enter data
        'Ex. Enters 500 as a Credit (should be -500 to balance) (500 * -1 = -500)            
        If Me.Type = "Credit" Then
            Me.Amount *= -1
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property Amount As Decimal
    Public Property Description As String

End Class
```

Then using the above for calculation...

```
'Create Calculate function
Public Function CalculateBalance() As Decimal
        Dim balanceDecimal As Decimal

        'Looping through TransactionsList again to get each Amount, 
        'this time to calculate total Balance
        For Each transaction In TransactionList
            balanceDecimal += transaction.Amount

        Next

        Return balanceDecimal 

End Function
```

Call in the Display Balance else/if block

```
    ElseIf Cb1.Text = "Display Balance" Then
            Lb1.Visible = False
            Lb2.Visible = False
            Lb3.Visible = True
            Tb1.Visible = False
            Tb2.Visible = False
            Lb3.Text = "$" 

            'Whatever control you want to display the balance in
            Tb1.Text = CalculateBalance().ToString("C2")

     End If
```

There are likely many solutions that you could use, and this is one of them that you can maybe get some other ideas from too. I hope I helped you find what you're trying to do.